# "echo" script to input random characters

Tags: bash, echo

I have a file and I want to input it with a random characters. For example I want to input what is inside `dropper.txt` file at `/sdcard/dropper.txt` into `finish.txt` at `/sdcard/finish.txt`

`dropper.txt` has a random characters and always change, but just at one time. And i want to input it to `finish.txt`

Maybe I can use `echo` command or somethingelse?
This Script for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the contents of `dropper.txt` to `finish.txt`

```
cat /sdcard/dropper.txt >> /sdcard/file.txt
```

will do the job.

Correct me, if I didn't get your question right.